# JS/ AJAX - Displaying correct message from json

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
var response = transport.responseJSON || transport.responseText.evalJSON(true) || {};

// console.log(response)
// log results
account: []
agreements: []
billing: []
order: {error: 1, message: "Ingenico ePayments Payment failed", goto_section: "payment"}
payment: []
shipping: []


alert(response.account.message);
```

Depending on what message comes back from the response is there a way I can loop through the AJAX response and display the associated message rather than hardcoding the value like in the above (response.account.message) as sometimes for example the error will come from a different section like:

```
account: {error: 1, message: "An account already exists for this email address."}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can I loop through the response and show the message rather than hardcoding all the values like: alert(response.account.message); alert(response.order.message); etc

Comment: If you have any control over the server side you should probably standardise the responses so that error responses have the same structure so that you could do `error.message`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probable want to use the for..in loop, which goes through the keys of an object or other iteratable. [More about for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

```js
var response = JSON.parse('{"account":{"error":1,"message":"your message"},"agreements":{"error":1,"message":"your second message"}}');

for (let type in response) {
  if (response[type].error) {
    var msg = response[type].message;

    console.log(type + " : '" + msg + "'");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a combination of `Object.values` and `Array.reduce`:

```
Object.values(response).reduce((acc, val) => {
  if (typeof val === 'Object' && typeof val.message !== 'undefined') {
    return val
  } else {
    return acc
  }
})
```

Or if you want an array of all messages:

```
Object.values(response)
  .filter(val => typeof val === 'Object')
  .filter(val => val.error === 1)
  .filter(val => typeof val.message !== 'undefined')
  .map(val => val.message);
```

See [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) docs

Comment: Brilliant thanks for that! Althought I can't seem to get it to work to test as the jslint thats being used doesn't seem to like ES6

Comment: It might behave better if you replace the arrow functions.